# C#/MonoTouch starter: How to change the color of a Label periodically?

Tags: timer, xamarin.ios, background-color, uicolor

i'm pretty new to programming in C# so please don't be mean with the following question.
I want to change the Background color of a label (MonoTouch) periodically, but it simply does't.
Anyway, the value of "_hue" is printed in the console periodically.

```
            public void _timer_elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _hue -= 0.1f;
            lblScreen.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromHSB (_hue,_sat,_bri);
            Console.WriteLine (_hue);
        }
```

Do you guys have a hint?

THANX! :-)

Comment: Please specify what kind of timer you are using.  If is is a `System.Timers.Timer`, you need to be using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` or `InvokeOnMainThread`.  You can't update the UI from a background thread.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers is likely right on target :-) and should convert his comment into an answer! Most existing UI toolkits (and that includes iOS) can only be **safely** from the main thread while *most* timers will run on a separate thread and notify you on this  (separate, not the main) thread. That requires you to call back into the main thread, using the suggested methods, in order to update any UI element.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public void _timer_elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _hue -= 0.1f;
        InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
            lblScreen.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromHSB (_hue,_sat,_bri);
        });
        Console.WriteLine (_hue);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/Threading) is a link on threading with MonoTouch.

You are likely receiving the timer event on a background thread.  Using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to update the UI will likely fix it.